# Problems to send email using Django EmailBackend

Tags: python, django, email

I don´t know what is wrong in my code. I´m trying to use send_mail using **django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend** but is not working. The security level of my gmail account is unlocked and the message in python looks like sent the email message. But the email didn´t arrive in my email account. Bellow are the codes that I´m using.

**settings.py**

```
# Email configuration
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<my_email>@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<my_password>'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

**views.py**

In the top of file

```
...
# send email
from django.core.mail import send_mail
...
```

In the request page

```
def contact_us(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = ContactFormEN(request.POST)
     
        if form.is_valid():
            
            sender_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            sender_email = form.cleaned_data['email']

            message = "{0} has sent you a new message:\n\n{1}".format(sender_name, form.cleaned_data['message'])
            send_mail('New Message from site', message, sender_email, ['<my_email>@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)

            return render(request, 'contact_us.html')
```

After run the code the console shows the follow message

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: New Message from site
From: <from_email>@gmail.com
To: <my_email>@gmail.com
Date: Mon, 15 Mar 2021 23:01:50 -0000
Message-ID:
 <161584931042.10464.14254641113919007176@my_machine_name>

Name has sent you a new message:

Test message
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you checked the spam folder just for sanity purposes. And have you tried a different email destination, perhaps a temporary one?

Comment: Also, you're not using your account password, you're using the one obtained from google like in [this tutorial](https://data-flair.training/blogs/django-send-email/), right?

Comment: Nothing in Spam, and Nothing in Trash. I created this account for this purpose

Comment: @BernardoDuarte I used this tutorial as reference. I´ll try to reproduce the tutorial as is trying to verify where is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you're using Gmail to send the emails. In that case, you have allow Less Secured Access to your gmail account. Follow these steps to do so:

**1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security (after you login to Google)

2. Scroll down to Less secure app access section and click TURN ON access**

Now Django should be able to send emails. If an email is rejected, the Gmail you connected to should send you a failure notice email.

Comment: Hello @vladthelad. I fix my code and configure my google account for less security but I found thid error right now ```But now I having another error. (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 124sm14647905qkn.121 - gsmtp') ```

Comment: Now it´s working. I change the password and the error was fixed

Comment: cool, let me know if more errors show up in regards to emails

Answer (score 1):

As [docs says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#console-backend) **django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend** should be used in a development environment as this backend will never send a real email.

In the django settings you must write:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: Hello @Tiki this works perfectly. But now I having another error.

```(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 124sm14647905qkn.121 - gsmtp')``` I did all the adjusts in Google Account but the error persist.

Comment: Changing the password the error was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Google claims that on May 5, 2022, they will shut down all "less secure apps": https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en.

You have to configure and secure your Google account and then you can "Use an App Password" in order to use `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`.